# Transformation and/or rotatation of an encrypted Image

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto, coordinate-transformation

Is it possible to encrypt an image, perform some transformation on the image i.e. rotate the encrypted image 90 degrees clockwise and then decrypt it to output the newly transformed image?

Finding references and sources on this subject is scarce.

Comment: First you will need a format preserving encryption so that the encrypted file can be recognised as an image by your image processing software.  That will almost certainly leak some information.  You need to decide if the leak is important or not.  Second, an encrypted image is effectively a random blur; rotating it will leave it still a random blur.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03249